# After using array get, how to remove the indexes in TCL

Tags: arrays, list, tcl

I have a proc which finishes off with an array. To return it I use "array get" to retrive a list. This list however does not only contain my array entrys, but also their index:

So my array `[ a b c d ]`  turns into a list `{ 0 a 1 b 2 c 3 d }`

How can i get rid of these index numbers without disturbing the list order?

Comment: Just a (belated) thought. Why? If you want a list, why not get the `proc` to generate a list?

Comment: Arrays have no order, you're not guaranteed to get that list. Use a dictionary and `dict values`.

Comment: In general I recommend using dictionaries if you're going to be passing the object to/from procs or wanting to do things like get the set of values (i.e., as potrzebie wrote, dict values). It just simplifies life, and the dictionary syntax is still pretty intuitive and simple to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest and most basic way I think would be to use a `foreach` loop:

```
% set list {0 a 1 b 2 c 3 d}
% set entrylist {}
% foreach {id entry} $list {
%     lappend entrylist $entry
% }
% puts $entrylist
a b c d
```

Answer (score 5):

A few options, apart from using `foreach`:

```
# [array get] actually returns a dictionary
puts [dict values $list]
```

```
# Could do this too
set entrylist {}
dict for {- entry} $list {
    lappend entrylist $entry
}
puts $entrylist
```

There are more possibilities in Tcl 8.6:

```
puts [lmap {- entry} $list {set entry}]
```

(There's also a `dict map`, but it isn't useful here.)

I like `dict values`…

Comment: Is there also a way to keep the element order of the array? Why is " The order of the pairs is undefined... " Cheers...

Comment: The order of the pairs "just is" undefined. That's the way Tcl works. If you are bothered, you can use one of the mechanisms that involves looping around the return from `array names` but sort it first. `dict` values is defined to return data in the order it was added to the dictionary. Honestly, as I suggested above, using an array _isn't_ the way to go if you have a choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an array and work with Tcl 8.5 or later, use  [`dict values`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/dict.htm#M26):

```
set arr(0) a
set arr(1) b
set arr(2) c
set arr(3) d

puts [dict values [array get arr]]
```

But it is better to use a simple [`list`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/list.htm):

```
set mylist {a b c d}
lset list 1 boo
puts [lindex $mylist 1]
lappend mylist eff
```

Arrays are associative. Always.